# Cómo saber la posición de un array bidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, array

Recojo los valores de un formulario mediante javascript de la siguiente manera

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nextinput = 0;
    function AgregarCampos(op){
    nextinput++;
    campo = '<input class="form-control" placeholder="'+op+'" type="text" size="20" id="campo'+op+'"&nbsp; name="campo['+op+'][]"&nbsp; /><br>';
    $("#campos"+op+"").append(campo);
}
    </script>
```

Cuando aplico el método var_export al array bidimensional $_POST["campo"] obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
array ( 1 => array ( 0 => 'Una categoría', ), 3 => array ( 0 => 'Otra categoría', ), 6 => array ( 0 => 'Una mas', 1 => 'Una mas', ), )
```

Bien, cuando obtenga los resultados correspondientes (Una categoría, Otra categoría, Una mas, Una mas), quiero obtener los números 1, 3 y 6.

¿Cómo podría obtenerlos?
Muchas gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array( 1 => array ( 0 => 'Una categoría'), 3 => array ( 0 => 'Otra categoría', ), 6 => array ( 0 => 'Una mas', 1 => 'Una mas', ), );
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo ("$value[0]"."="."$key")."<br>";
}
```

Esto tal vez pueda servirte.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener los indices que te proporciona el array, php te provee de una funcion para este fin:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php

$keys = array_keys($_POST['campo'][1]);

esto te devuelve un array asociativo como:

```
array ( 
    0 => 1, 
    1 => 3, 
    2 => 6
);
```

en el que las claves son indices continuos, y el valor de cada elemento es  el key que buscas.